# Zend Framework Subdirectory

Tags: php, zend-framework

Hey so in Zend Framework I have a controller called Days
and I have an action called sunday.

So when I go to my website: mywebsite.com/days/sunday/ - this is going to be using my default index.phtml which is fine.

Now I have another phtml page called goodmorning which I want it to remain in the sunday action.

so it reads like this:
mywebsite.com/days/sunday/goodmorning/
mywebsite.com/days/sunday/goodafternoon/
mywebsite.com/days/sunday/night/

How do I do that?

```
  class daysController extends Zend_Controller_Action

  {

      public function sundayAction()

      {



      }

  }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
class DaysController extends Zend_Controller_Action
{
    public function sundayAction()
    {
        $params = getParams();
        switch ($params[0]) {
            case 'goodmorning':
                $partial = 'goodmorning';
                break;
            case 'goodafternoon':
                $partial = 'goodafternoon';
                break;
            case 'night':
            default:
                $partial = 'night';
                break;
        }
        $this->_helper->viewRenderer($partial);
    }
}
```

Although, you should use http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.usage to set up a custom route. `days/:day/:greeting` for example.

Comment: $this->render($partial.'.phtml'); is wrong because it will cause output directly in controller, so it will be impossible to cancel it in postDispatch actions in Helpers or Plugins if needed. Much more sufficient vay is to use the following:

$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setRender($partial);

Answer (score 0):

> So when I go to my website: mywebsite.com/days/sunday/ - this is going to be using my default index.phtml which is fine.

Wrong, it'll call `sunday.phtml`, **views** are mapped with **actions**

However, depending on the involved parameters, you may both use the `Zend_Controller_Action::render()` method or use `$this->partial('goodmorning.phtml')` in your view, it may have sense is you've some common part between all the views and want to change only the remaining part.

You may want to describe more accurately what you want to do, and we may suggest you a better approach actually.